# European cloud hosting provider

Tags: hosting, cloud-hosting

I'm trying to find a good european cloud hosting provider. For legal reasons we can not host our service in the US or with an american company operating in the European union (rackspace).

All we want is a couple of linux machines that we can manage our selves.

Any good suggestions?

Best regards,

Niclas

Comment: More suitable for serverfault than SO, voted to move it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong on stackoverflow.

Anyway, I don't know what do you mean with "good"

you have no criterias... so if you want a cheap&good one check
http://www.alvotech.de/

> server in germany or netherland (your choice)

or if you want a very secure and one of the best for business I know of you can try
http://www.artmotion.eu/
it's not cheap but I think it's well worth it

> server in switzerland